# Change bounceback email address for zencart

Tags: php, phpmailer, zen-cart

I am not sure if this belongs here or at serverfault but the thing is, I have a zencart installation which sends mails using phpMailer( using 'PHP' mode,that is the php's mail() function). Now when these mails fail they bounce to a particular mail address, whereas I need to make sure that the bounced mail always goes to the "From" address which sent it. I think this is beyond the scope of phpMailer, but is there any way for me to achieve this properly? I really don't wanna run a cron job, check the bounce email inbox and then send the mails where intended. Is there any other way?

Oh and if this is any help, I have access to cPanel, and WHM for the server, so if there is any settings that I need to modify, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to get your email delivered correctly is to use SMTPAUTH and provide credentials for a valid SMTP mailbox. That way the "from" address and bounce address will be handled by the SMTP server.